# Why is Joomla 3's JModelBase deprecated? What should be used instead?

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

Joomla 3 introduced a new MVC classes described here [Joomla MVC manual](https://developer.joomla.org/manual/chap-Joomla_Platform_Manual-MVC.html) but the classes seem to be deprecated now (for example: [JModelBase class docs](https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JModelBase.html)) and I can't figure out what I should actually use to develop an MVC component for Joomla 3. Which base classes should be used?

Comment: I would suggest asking on the Joomla Stack Exchange [joomla.se] but as phrased the title is really not a coding question.   What should I use instead might be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a look at some of the core Jooma 3.0 extensions you'll find as of 3.9.14 they are using the following in the banners component:

Site:

- item- `JModelLegacy`
- list - `JModelList`

Admin

- item- `JModelAdmin`
- list - `JModelList`

However, as Joomla 4 is almost here and newer versions of joomla 3 support it, I would use the new classes:

Site:

- item- `class <Component>Model<Section> extends \Joomla\CMS\MVC\Model\ItemModel`
- form - `class <Component>Model<Section>Form extends \Joomla\CMS\MVC\Model\FormModel`
- list - `class <Component>Model<Sections> extends \Joomla\CMS\MVC\Model\ListModel`

Admin:

- item- `class <Component>Model<Section> extends \Joomla\CMS\MVC\Model\AdminModel`
- list - `class <Component>Model<Sections> extends \Joomla\CMS\MVC\Model\ListModel`

Also see [Joomla 3 MVC component docs](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_an_MVC_Component/Adding_a_model_to_the_site_part)

And [Joomla API Docs](https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/Joomla.CMS.MVC.Model.BaseDatabaseModel.html)